# How can I do compiled binding or x:Bind to indexed property using string as an index?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, binding, compiled

I'm trying to use compiled binding I have a property `Errors` that I used to bind using the regular binding like `{Binding Errors[PropertyName]}`. However, when I tried to use `{x:Bind VM.Errors[PropertyName]}`, I got this error

> "Invalid binding path 'VM.Errors[PropertyName]' : Expected a digit"

I also tried to use quotes like `VM.Errors['PropertyName']` but it does'nt solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work. Microsoft writes:

```
{Binding Groups[2].Title}
```

> Binds to the specified item in the collection. Only integer-based indexes are supported.

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt210946.aspx at the end of the page. I event tried implementing IReadOnlyDictionary oe IDictionary, but no success.

Its interessting because on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185586.aspx they say:

> For example, consider a business object where there is a list of "Teams" (ordered list), each of which has a dictionary of "Players" where each player is keyed by last name. An example property path to a specific player on the second team is: "Teams[1](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1831878).Players[Smith]". (You use 1 to indicate the second item in "Teams" because the list is zero-indexed.)

**Update**

My support case at [Microsoft connnect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1831878) was closed. They write:

> Thank you for reporting this issue as well as providing a sample project. The suggested scenario was not supported in Windows 10 RTM. We are however considering adding such support to a future update to Windows 10.

Comment: I added a but report on ms connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1831878

Comment: I voted up your report to conenct.microsoft. I really need this functionality. Otherwise, I would have to bind some of the codes not using x:bind. Thanks.

Comment: FYI: Microsoft has closed the bug report as "is working as designed"